# How to copy the id_rsa.pub keys in remote server authorized_key without knowing the remote server password

Tags: linux, command-line

I want to login in remote server and I don't know the remote server password. I am doing the below command

```
cat id_rsa.pub | ssh root@10.19.119.134 | cat > authorized_keys
```

or

```
scp id_rsa.pub root@10.19.119.134:~./ssh/authorized_keys
```

But it asking for password

Comment: I believe there has to be some dire misunderstanding at some parts of `ssh` what `ssh` does on your side. With `ssh` you want to make sure that only persons who are permitted can access your server and obviously you have to authenticate the identity of those who want to login for that. You can do that using e.g. username and password, or public key authentication. But obviously you can't give yourself the right to authentication using latter without using some other authentication method like former, otherwise just anyone could do that and the `ssh` server would need no authentication at all.

Comment: You would have to contact the admin of the server to discuss in what way you should be given access to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no possible way to access to server and put or edit anything without any authentication, because in the end you are trying to edit `authorized_keys` file, and if there is no authentication you could copy and paste any thing you want to that file and that will be a horrible security vulnerability

Comment: I tried but it asking for password